# nomes repetidos mysql pelo select

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando mostrar uma tabela onde apenas apareça uma vez o nome do autor em que o livro dele esteja com estoque=0, entretanto eu estou recebendo o nome de todos autores de forma duplicada, até mesmo quando o autor não tem estoque =0.
Eu tenho a tabela escreve que tem autor_idautor e livro_idlivro, ambas são chaves estrangeiras em autor e livro.

```
select nome from autor,livro where estoque=0;


 Autor
 +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | idautor  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | nome     | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | datanasc | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+



 Livro
 +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | idlivro         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | titulo          | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | preco           | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | estoque         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | editora         | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | genero_idgenero | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
 +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


 Escreve
 +---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | autor_idautor | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | livro_idlivro | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 +---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: pode por gentileza por a estrutura das duas tabelas?

Comment: Se você tem duas tabelas (autor e livro) deve especificar alguma forma de ligação entre os registros de cada uma das tabelas.

Comment: @JasarOrion coloquei as duas tabelas usando describe mesmo.

Comment: @anonimo eu tenho tabela escreve que tem autor_idautor, livro_idlivro. ambas são chaves estrangeiras na tabela autor e livro, respectivamente.

Comment: Pelo que postou acima não me parece que nenhum dos dois campos seja chave estrangeira. Talvez na tabela livro você tenha a indicação de seu autor ou ainda, no caso geral, ter uma outra tabela correlacionando autores e livros (relacionamento N:N).

Comment: após declarar as tabelas eu fiz o seguinte comando, alter table escreve add foreign key (autor_idautor) references autor (idautor);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pode realizar da seguinte forma:
Primeiro você cria um campo `idautor` na sua tabela `Livro`

depois a consulta fica assim:

```
SELECT 
   a.nome, l.estoque as total 
from 
   Autor a
join Escreve e on e.autor_idautor = a.idautor
join Livro l on l.idlivro = e.livro_idlivro
where
   l.estoque < 1
GROUP BY a.nome;
```

Comment: eu tenho a tabela escreve, não mencionei antes. ela tem autor_idautor, livro_idlivro. ambas são chaves estrangeiras na tabela autor e livro, respectivamente, eu poderia usar ela como referência?

Comment: sim pode basta por ela no join. da um update com essa outra tabela que vc tem para eu atualizar minha resposta.

Comment: Atualizei com a tabela escreve.

Comment: atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Deu erro pois não existe relacionamento entre as duas tabelas, o que eu aconselho por exemplo é colocar um campo de "idautor" na tabela de livros, e fazer o relacionamento em cima desse campo.

EX:

```
select nome 
    from autor,livro
    where autor.idautor = livro.idautor
    and estoque = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade ele vai repetir independente de quantos livros de cada autor tiverem, já que você não fez o join das duas tabelas.

Depois de fazer o join, use a palavra "distinct" após o select, é a maneira mais simples de conseguir os nomes sem repetir.

Comment: desculpe, mas você poderia mostrar um exemplo?. Não faço mínima ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: Eu estou no celular agora, então fica complicado, mas vou deixar um link pra um artigo bem explicado de como funciona, já avisando que do jeito que suas tabelas estão, você não vai conseguir, já que não tem nenhuma coluna que relacione os dados. https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/joins-em-sql